# Subquery returns more than 1 row using my sql

Tags: mysql

> I am trying to make a select statement that selects the id user (employee or leader or manager) and full name, from a MySQL database.  depending on the id dept , id priorty . The code is:

```
PROCEDURE `get_parent`(id_dept int, id_priorty int )
BEGIN
if(select employee_tb.id_dept  from employee_tb where (employee_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&3=id_priorty))>0
then
begin
select id_employee ,full_name,3 as type from employee_tb;
end;
elseif(select leader_tb.id_dept from leader_tb where (leader_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=2))>0
 then
 begin
 select id_leader, full_name, 2 as type from leader_tb;
 end;
 elseif(select manager_tb.id_dept from manager_tb where (manager_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=1))>0
 then 
 begin
 select id_manager, full_name, 1 as type from manager_tb;
 end;
 else
 select "failed"as result ;
 end if;
END
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We could do with some more information, for example why do you think that there should only be one record returned when all of the `SELECT` lines allow for more than one e.g. `if(select employee_tb.id_dept  from employee_tb where (employee_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&3=id_priorty))>0` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_employee ,full_name,3 as type from employee_tb;

select id_leader, full_name, 2 as type from leader_tb;

select id_manager, full_name, 1 as type from manager_tb;
```

those 3 lines in your code after checking condition selects all records from table anyway.

To fix this issue:

```
PROCEDURE `get_parent`(id_dept int, id_priorty int )
BEGIN
if(select employee_tb.id_dept  from employee_tb where (employee_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&3=id_priorty))>0
then
begin
select id_employee ,full_name,3 as type from employee_tb where (employee_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&3=id_priorty);
end;
elseif(select leader_tb.id_dept from leader_tb where (leader_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=2))>0
 then
 begin
 select id_leader, full_name, 2 as type from leader_tb where (leader_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=2);
 end;
 elseif(select manager_tb.id_dept from manager_tb where (manager_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=1))>0
 then 
 begin
 select id_manager, full_name, 1 as type from manager_tb where (manager_tb.id_dept=id_dept&&id_priorty=1);
 end;
 else
 select "failed"as result ;
 end if;
END
```

it will of course give one record if there is one record that matches this where clause.

Comment: still told me the same error and I have note I want in my selection give me all rows in one table (employee or leader or manager ) when match the conditions that the priority and id dept same